# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected gru_5_input to have shape (None, None, 10) but got array with shape (1, 4, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am trying to make hourly predictions using a recurrent neural network using TensorFlow and Keras in Python.I have assigned my inputs of the neural network to be (None, None, 5) shown in my [image: summary].

However, I am getting the errorː

> `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected gru_3_input to have shape (None, None, 10) but got array with shape (1, 4, 1)` My MVCE code isː

```
%matplotlib inline
#!pip uninstall keras
#!pip install keras==2.1.2
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import DataFrame 
import math




#####Create the Recurrent Neural Network###


model = Sequential()


model.add(GRU(units=5, 
                return_sequences=True,
                input_shape=(None, num_x_signals)))

## This line is going to map the above 512 values to just 1 (num_y_signal)
model.add(Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))

if False:
    from tensorflow.python.keras.initializers import RandomUniform

    # Maybe use lower init-ranges.##### I may have to change these during debugging####
    init = RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05)

    model.add(Dense(num_y_signals,
                    activation='linear',
                    kernel_initializer=init))

warmup_steps = 5

def loss_mse_warmup(y_true, y_pred):

    #
    # Ignore the "warmup" parts of the sequences
    # by taking slices of the tensors.
    y_true_slice = y_true[:, warmup_steps:, :]
    y_pred_slice = y_pred[:, warmup_steps:, :]

    # These sliced tensors both have this shape:
    # [batch_size, sequence_length - warmup_steps, num_y_signals]

    # Calculate the MSE loss for each value in these tensors.
    # This outputs a 3-rank tensor of the same shape.
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true_slice,
                                        predictions=y_pred_slice)



    loss_mean = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

    return loss_mean

optimizer = RMSprop(lr=1e-3) ### This is somthing related to debugging 



model.compile(loss=loss_mse_warmup, optimizer=optimizer)#### I may have to make the output a singnal rather than the whole data set 

print(model.summary())


model.fit_generator(generator=generator,
                    epochs=20,
                    steps_per_epoch=100,
                    validation_data=validation_data)
```

I am not sure why this could be, but i believe it could something to do with reshaping my training and testing data. ɪ have also attached my full [image: traceback] error message to my code to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: shape of validation_data and and one batch of  training_generator is not same.

Comment: shape of your `validation_data` is`(1,4,1)` which is not acceptable as input.

Comment: @krishna, thank you for replying, would it be possible to to get help with how to have my validation set to be (none,none,10) as I was under the impression that I had done this lineː model.add(GRU(units=5, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, num_x_signals)))

Comment: You can modify the training generator for and create another for generating validation data.

Comment: @krishna would it be possible to have an example of this that I could include in my code? As I am really confused with this

Comment: sorry for not helping. But the main idea is you've to make the shape of validation and train data same. I'm unable to understand few parts of your code that's why I can't help. But I'm trying.

Comment: @krishna I do really appreciate your help! Thank you! I could  answer the parts that do not make sense in order to get this working? Also I am using : https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/23_Time-Series-Prediction.ipynb . My code is  almost identical to this  If this may help with getting me out of this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure about the correctness but here it is:

```
%matplotlib inline
#!pip uninstall keras
#!pip install keras==2.1.2
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import DataFrame 
import math
import numpy 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
import datetime
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, GRU, Embedding
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard, ReduceLROnPlateau


datetime = [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0) + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(10)]




X=np.array([2.25226244,1.44078451,0.99174488,0.71179491,0.92824542,1.67776948,2.96399534,5.06257161,7.06504245,7.77817664
               ,0.92824542,1.67776948,2.96399534,5.06257161,7.06504245,7.77817664])

y= np.array([0.02062136,0.00186715,0.01517354,0.0129046 ,0.02231125,0.01492537,0.09646542,0.28444476,0.46289928,0.77817664
                ,0.02231125,0.01492537,0.09646542,0.28444476,0.46289928,0.77817664])

X = X[1:11]
y= y[1:11]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':datetime,'y':y,'X':X})



df['t']= [x for x in range(10)]
df['X-1'] = df['X'].shift(-1)


x_data = df['X-1'].fillna(0)

y_data = y 

num_data = len(x_data) 

    #### training and testing split####
train_split = 0.6
num_train = int(train_split*num_data)   
num_test = num_data-num_train## number of observations in test set


    #input train test 
x_train = x_data[0:num_train].reshape(-1, 1)
x_test = x_data[num_train:].reshape(-1, 1)
    #print (len(x_train) +len( x_test))

    #output train test 
y_train = y_data[0:num_train].reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = y_data[num_train:].reshape(-1, 1)
    #print (len(y_train) + len(y_test))


    ### number of input signals 
num_x_signals = x_data.shape[0]
   # print (num_x_signals)

    ## number of output signals##

num_y_signals = y_data.shape[0]
    #print (num_y_signals)

    ####data scalling'###

x_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
x_train_scaled = x_scaler.fit_transform(x_train)



x_test_scaled = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1)).fit_transform(x_test)

y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
y_train_scaled = y_scaler.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test_scaled = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1)).fit_transform(y_test)



def batch_generator(batch_size, sequence_length):
    """
    Generator function for creating random batches of training-data.
    """

    # Infinite loop.  providing the neural network with random data from the 
    # datase for x and y 
    while True:
        # Allocate a new array for the batch of input-signals.
        x_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_x_signals)
        x_batch = np.zeros(shape=x_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        # Allocate a new array for the batch of output-signals.
        y_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_y_signals)
        y_batch = np.zeros(shape=y_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        # Fill the batch with random sequences of data.
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # Get a random start-index.
            # This points somewhere into the training-data.
            idx = np.random.randint(num_train - sequence_length)

            # Copy the sequences of data starting at this index.
            x_batch[i] = x_train_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]
            y_batch[i] = y_train_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]

        yield (x_batch, y_batch)


batch_size =20




sequence_length = 2 


generator = batch_generator(batch_size=batch_size,
                            sequence_length=sequence_length)

x_batch, y_batch = next(generator)




#########Validation Set Start########

def batch_generator(batch_size, sequence_length):
    """
    Generator function for creating random batches of training-data.
    """

    # Infinite loop.  providing the neural network with random data from the 
    # datase for x and y 
    while True:
        # Allocate a new array for the batch of input-signals.
        x_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_x_signals)
        x_batch = np.zeros(shape=x_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        # Allocate a new array for the batch of output-signals.
        y_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_y_signals)
        y_batch = np.zeros(shape=y_shape, dtype=np.float16)

        # Fill the batch with random sequences of data.
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # Get a random start-index.
            # This points somewhere into the training-data.
            idx = np.random.randint(num_train - sequence_length)

            # Copy the sequences of data starting at this index.
            x_batch[i] = x_test_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]
            y_batch[i] = y_test_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]

        yield (x_batch, y_batch)
validation_data= next(batch_generator(batch_size,sequence_length))

# validation_data = (np.expand_dims(x_test_scaled, axis=0),
#                     np.expand_dims(y_test_scaled, axis=0))

#Validation set end

#####Create the Recurrent Neural Network###


model = Sequential()


model.add(GRU(units=5, 
                return_sequences=True,
                input_shape=(None, num_x_signals)))

## This line is going to map the above 512 values to just 1 (num_y_signal)
model.add(Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))

if False:
    from tensorflow.python.keras.initializers import RandomUniform

    # Maybe use lower init-ranges.##### I may have to change these during debugging####
    init = RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05)

    model.add(Dense(num_y_signals,
                    activation='linear',
                    kernel_initializer=init))

warmup_steps = 5

def loss_mse_warmup(y_true, y_pred):

    #
    # Ignore the "warmup" parts of the sequences
    # by taking slices of the tensors.
    y_true_slice = y_true[:, warmup_steps:, :]
    y_pred_slice = y_pred[:, warmup_steps:, :]

    # These sliced tensors both have this shape:
    # [batch_size, sequence_length - warmup_steps, num_y_signals]

    # Calculate the MSE loss for each value in these tensors.
    # This outputs a 3-rank tensor of the same shape.
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true_slice,
                                        predictions=y_pred_slice)



    loss_mean = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

    return loss_mean

optimizer = RMSprop(lr=1e-3) ### This is somthing related to debugging 



model.compile(loss=loss_mse_warmup, optimizer=optimizer)#### I may have to make the output a singnal rather than the whole data set 

print(model.summary())


model.fit_generator(generator=generator,
                    epochs=20,
                    steps_per_epoch=100,
                    validation_data=validation_data)
```

I've only changed part of code between `validation set start` and `validation set end`.

Comment: @Khan11 weird training and val loss.

Comment: @ krishna Thank you very much! This is running so far!. Just out of curiosity as I new to Python and machine learning. I wanted to ask, what is odd about the training and validation loss?? Thank you

Comment: We want machine learning model to learn something. So how do we measure the learning? we do it by measuring loss. But learning doesn't mean that it should learn only for training set, it should perform also well on unseen data.  so validation loss is unseen data, we check the performance of model after every epoch  and see whether it is increasing or not. In general training loss always decrease as the # of epoch increases.But this is not the case for validation loss sometime it may remain stagnant sometime it may increase, best is the case when it increases.

Comment: Right okay so that is really helpful! My codes loss function and validation losses are currently zero:loss:" 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00". I assume this is incorrect. Could this be due to the fact that I have written my codes to measure the losses incorrectly? Or could this be another defect within the algorithm?  Thank you for breaking this down for me! I didn't realise it was that straight forward.

Comment: Oops. Last word of my previous comment should be " decreases". I'd would advise you to understand thoroughly what's going behind. Don't rush to see fancy results. I'm also a beginner. lol.

Comment: Thank you for your help till now. I'm a beginner but my deadlines require fast results soon! Again, really appreciated your help!